# How do I find the first dot, hash, or parens in a String?

Tags: python

Im trying to figure out how to find the first dot, hash, or parens in a string.

Example:`test.case#tester`, I need to find the location of the `.` as it comes before the #.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like a homework but you simply have to iterate over the string and check each character.

```
test_string = "test.case#tester"
look_for = [".", "#", "(", ")"]

for index, single_char in enumerate(test_string):
  if single_char in look_for:
    print index
    break
```

Comment: I promise, it's not homework! Im just kind of new to python and trying to figure out how to do some less common things in a new language!

Comment: I chose this one as the answer because syntactically this follows some very fundamental principles that are common in python! I've tested them all and they all seem to work but this one follows these:

`Beautiful is better than ugly.
Simple is better than complex.
Readability counts.`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> testcase='test.case#tester'
>>> tokens = ['.','#','(',')']
>>> min([testcase.find(i) if testcase.find(i) > 0 else len(testcase) for i in tokens])
4
```

if the minimum index is greater than the length of the string, there is no symbol in this string.

Answer (score 1):

```
min(x for x in [mystring.find('.'), mystring.find('#'), mystring.find(')'), mystring.find('(')] if x >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
next(i for i,c in enumerate(my_str) if c in {'.','#','(',')'})
```